Is there any link between PDE and Ergodic theory?
A friend of mine wanted to have a meeting about the book by Einslieder and Ward titled "Ergodic Theory with a View Towards Number Theory." The problem is that my friend works in number theory, while I study PDEs.
I wanted to check online if there was any link between these two fields, but I couldn't find anything satisfying (except for something about the Boltzmann Hypothesis, but I couldn't find any good articles on the math surrounding it).
So, does anyone have a topic suggestion or can tell me about any connections between these two theories (PDE and ergodic systems) ?

Using knowledge of what both field study, and a little research on various research paper archives, there is indeed common ground between PDEs and ergodic systems. This connection is substantial enough to facilitate a fruitful meeting between you and your number theory friend.
The main ways in which the two are connected are:

Stochastic Processes: Both fields can involve stochastic processes. In PDEs, stochastic partial differential equations (SPDEs) introduce randomness into the system, which can be studied using ergodic theory to understand long-term behavior. SPDEs describe systems influenced by random forces. Ergodic theory helps in understanding the equilibrium and invariant measures of such systems.

Dynamical Systems: The study of dynamical systems is relevant to both fields. PDEs often describe the evolution of dynamical systems, while ergodic theory examines their long-term statistical properties. Random dynamical systems governed by PDEs can exhibit ergodic behavior, meaning their statistical properties can be described independently of initial conditions after a long time. An example is the Navier-Stokes equations with random perturbations.

Mixing and Stability: Ergodic theory’s concepts of mixing and stability have analogs in the analysis of PDEs, where solutions' stability and long-term behavior are of interest.


To explore the link further, consider the following case studies, which include research papers, textbooks, and dissertations. They may provide some ideas and structure for your meeting.

Ergodic theory for Stochastic PDEs, by Martin Hairer (lecture notes): A concise set of lecture notes from a lecture course at Warwick University, which explicitly explores the link. See here: https://www.hairer.org/notes/Imperial.pdf
Ergodicity and mixing for stochastic partial differential equations by Jean Bricmont (research article): This paper discusses how stochastic partial differential equations contribute to the ergodic and mixing properties of random dynamical systems. See here: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212412
Ergodicity for Infinite Dimensional Systems by G. Da Prato and J. Zabczyk (textbook): This book is devoted to the asymptotic properties of solutions of stochastic evolution equations in infinite-dimensional spaces, including the Navier-Stokes equation. See here:  https://www.cambridge.org/af/universitypress/subjects/mathematics/differential-and-integral-equations-dynamical-systems-and-co/ergodicity-infinite-dimensional-systems
Dynamical Systems and Probabilistic Methods in Partial Differential Equations by Percy Deift, C. David Levermore, and C. Eugene Wayne (lecture notes): A summer seminar set of notes which provides a good guide to the link. Ergodic theory is explicitly mentioned several times. See here: https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/tr/pdf/ADA303008.pdf
Ergodicity Results for the Stochastic Navier–Stokes Equations by A Debussche (textbook): A chapter from a Springer book on Mathematical Fluid Dynamics that explores the link applied to the Navier-Stokes equations. See here: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-36297-2_2

I hope that this provides some guidance to yourself, as well as anyone else who may be interested. If you have any further questions about any of these resources, feel free to ask. I wish you luck with the meeting!

yep, thank you very much !
